# How to return a / respond with (java)script from express.js using JADE

Tags: express, pug

I'd like to respond to ajax calls on my express.js application with javascript scripts that will be evaluated in the client. How do I handle that with JADE as the template to construct these scripts dynamically?

Thx alot.
Markus

Answer (score 0):

In your app:

```
app.get('/demo.js', function(req, res) {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
  res.render('script', { value : Math.random() });
});
```

In your template (`script.jade`):

```
|var someVar = #{value};
```

Test:

```
$ http get localhost:3012/demo.js
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: text/javascript
Date: Fri, 10 May 2013 14:30:54 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express

var someVar = 0.9364965052809566;
```